# Regex (re2 googlesheets) multiple values in multiline cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, re2

Getting stuck on how to read and pretty up these values from a multiline cell via arrayformula.

Im using regex as preceding line can vary.

**just formulas please, no custom code**

The first column looks like a set of these:
```
[config]
name = the_name
texture = blah.dds
cost = 1000

[effect0]
value = 1000
type = ATTR_A

[effect1]
value = 8
type = ATTR_B

[feature0]
name = feature_blah

[components]
0 = comp_one,1

[resources]
res_one = 1
res_five = 1
res_four = 1

```
<br/>
Where to be useful elsewhere, at minimum it needs each [tag] set ([effect\d], [feature\d], ect) to be in one column each, for example the 'effects' column would look like:
```

ATTR_A:1000,ATTR_B:8

```
and so on.



Desired output can also be seen in the included spreadsheet


<br/>
<b>Here is the example spreadsheet:</b>

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1arMaaT56S_STTvRr2OxCINTyF-VvZ95Pm3mljju8Cxw/edit?usp=sharing


**Current REGEXREPLACE**

Kinda works, finds each 'type' and 'value' great, just cant figure out how to extract just that from the rest, tried capture (and non-capturing) groups before and after but didnt work
```

=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE($A3:$A,"[\n.]*[effect\d][\n.]*(.*)\n(.*)","1:$1 2:$2"))

```
**Current SUBSTITUTE + REGEXEXTRACT + REGEXREPLACE**

A different approach entirely, also kinda works, longer form though and left with having to parse the values out of that string, where got stuck again. Idea was to use this to simplify, then regexreplace like above. Getting stuck removing content around the final matches though, and if can do that then above approach is fine too.
```

// First ran a substitute
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A3:$A,char(10),";"),";;",char(10)))
// Then variation of this (gave up on single line 'effect/d' so broke it up to try and get it working)
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A<>"",IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A,"(?m)^(?:[effect0]);(.*)*$")&";;")&""&IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A,"(?m)^(?:[effect1]);(.*)*$")&";;")&""&IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A,"(?m)^(?:[effect2]);(.*)*$")&";;"),""))
// Then use regexreplace like above
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE($B3:$B,"value = (.*);type = (.*);;","1:$1 2:$2"))

```
**--EDIT--**

Also, as my updated 'Desired Output' sheet shows (see timestamped comment below), bonus kudos if you can also extract just the values of matching 'type's to those extra columns (see spreadsheet). 

All good if you cant though, just realized would need that too for lookups.

**--END OF EDIT--**

<br/>
Ive tried dozens of things, discarding each in turn, had a quick look in version history to grab out two promising attempts and shared them in separate sheets.

One of these also used SUBSTITUTE to simplify input column, im happy for a solution using either RAW or the SUBSTITUTE results.


<br/>
**Potentially Useful links:**

https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax



<br/>

<b>Just some more words:</b>

I also have looked at dozens of stackoverflow and google support pages, so tried both REGEXEXTRACT and REGEXREPLACE, both promising but missing that final tweak. And i tried dozens of tweaks already on both.


Any help would be great, and hopefully help others in future since examples with spreadsheets are great since every new REGEX seems to be a new adventure ;) 

<br/>
P.S. if we can think of better title for OP, please say in comment or your answer :)
```

Comment: EDIT - timestamping an edit as made slight change to extra columns in 'DESIRED OUTPUT' sheet, to make it clearer the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: 0]

paste in **B3**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(C3:E<>"", C2:E2&":"&C3:E, )),,999^99))), " ", ", "))
```

paste in **C3**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT($A3:$A, "(\d+)\ntype = "&C2)))
```

paste in **D3**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT($A3:$A, "(\d+)\ntype = "&D2)))
```

paste in **E3**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT($A3:$A, "(\d+)\ntype = "&E2)))
```

paste in **F3**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A, "\[feature\d+\]\nname = (.*)")))
```

paste in **G3**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A, "\[components\]\n\d+ = (.*)")))
```

paste in **H3**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A3:A, "\n", ", "), "\[resources\], (.*)"), "["),,1), ", , $", )))
```

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17qNspnX4CO9E8Ge8HpoeQZg20iA8h3KdujUXTRahkIs/edit#gid=736406624)

Comment: Excellent solution. Very elegant.

Comment: Very elegant, and thanks for showing the compounding query and uses of SPLIT, REGEXEXTRACT and REGEXREPLACE, gives me and anyone else who finds this in future lots more to work with :)

Answer (score 1):

This was a fun exercise. :-)

Caveat first: I have added some "input data". Examples:

```
[feature1]
name = feature_active_spoiler2

[components]
0 = spoiler,1
1 = spoilerA, 2
```

So the output has "extra" output.

See the tab [ADW's Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mYFK-r08XWipfkTf1QUFXwK63Ipp8KCtQ4VWL_NLX0c/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i see what you mean, thats some serious fun nesting there ;)